# CSS not getting applied when called from external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I try to set min width container-fluid for my SpringBoot apps UI.
I create report.css

```
.report {
  min-width: 1200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Add it to html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="../../resources/css/report.css" th:src="@{/resources/css/report.css}"/>
<body class="container-fluid report">
```

But it doesn't work.
How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please try adding a background color through the class and see if the CSS is actually working or not..

Comment: @Lal I add background:black; it doesnt work

Comment: are you sure that the `<link>` tag is added in the `<head>` itself?

Comment: @Lal yes, its right after js link. js works

Comment: Please check the answer posted below. my bad.. didn't notice the `src` attribute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `href` instead of `src` in `<link>`

To link an external stylesheet in your HTML page, you will have to use the `href` attribute and not `src` attribute.

Read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)